# Can you place the object being constructed into a static field from another class?

Tags: java, static

Suppose I have a class, X, with a static list. Then, suppose another class, Y, instantiates the class Z.

Is it possible in Z's constructor to put Z at the end of X's list. The alternative is to instantiate Z in Y, and then have Y manually put Z in X's list. Which way is better?

Here is some code:

```
public class X { 
    public static List list = new List() ; 
} 

public class Y { 
    makeZ() { 
         Z xObject = new Z() ;
    } 
} 

public class Z { 
    Z() {
         // put Z into X's list
    } 
}
```

The alternative Y class would be, which works. . .

```
public class Y { 
    makeZ() { 
         Z xObject = new Z() ;
         X.list.put(Z) ; 
    } 
}
```

Of course, in this case, Z's constructor doesnt put itself into X's list since Y's makeZ() method does it.

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Comment: Provide some code if you want anyone to actually understand your question.

Comment: This smells pretty bad. Since you're asking for general design advice (which way is "better"): `list` shouldn't be static.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a complete (almost) program that may answer the first part of your question :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

public class TestClass   {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Y y = new Y();
    y.makeZ();
    Iterator<Object> it = X.list.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext())
        System.out.println(it.next());
    }   
}

class X { 
  public static List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
} 

class Y { 
void makeZ() { 
     Z xObject1 = new Z(10) ;
     Z xObject2 = new Z(11) ;
    } 
} 

class Z {
int a;
Z(int j) {
     // put Z into X's list
    a = j;
    X.list.add(this);
}
public String toString() {
    return a + "";
}
}
```

and for the second part of your question :
I'm always committed to just initialize objects in constructors.
If adding an object from the z class is part of the initialization I think it's the good choice otherwise do it somewhere else.(always keep your codes tidy)

Answer (score 0):

In the constructor you have access to `this`, which represent the object being initilized, so you could use it as any other object.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible in Z's constructor to put Z at the end of X's list

Yes, if Z has access to X's list.

> Which way is better?

This depends on the semantics. Is the list something closely related with Z's responsibilities or more with Y's?

Answer (score 0):

all you need to do is ensuring the x variable can be accessed on global scope or have a method that do that and while instantiate Z just use this  method to add it.